# Every maximal ideal is prime... why not converse?

Tags: abstract-algebra, ring-theory, ideals

I know that every maximal ideal is prime but I don't see why the converse doesn't hold.

Intuitively it seems like every prime ideal should be maximal. Off the top of my head I can't imagine how we could have an ideal that would 'contain' a prime ideal.

Comment: Take $(x) \subset \mathbb{Z}[x]$

Comment: every prime idea is Not maximal just for the same reason as every integral domain is not a field...

Comment: I was not joking.. you take an integral domain which is not a field and for sure i know you can easily see corresponding relation between prime and maximal ideals

Comment: @PrahladVaidyanathan What ideal other than $\mathbb{Z}[x]$ itself contains $(x)$?

Comment: $(x) \subset (2,x)$

Comment: The ideals containing $(x)$ correspond to ideals in $\mathbb{Z}[x]/(x)\cong \mathbb{Z}$. So, for instance, the ideal $(2,x)$ contains $(x)$ and is non-trivial

Comment: *intuitively it seems like every prime ideal should be maximal.* If that were true then prime and maximal ideals would be the same things, and that doesn't seem intuitive at all.

Comment: @AlgebraGuy Prahlad's answer is really good because it shows you that chains of prime ideals can exist. Maximal ideals can never obviously make long chains. To expand upon the exmaple, here is a chain of prime ideals in $Z[w,x,y,z]$:$\{0\}\subseteq (w)\subseteq (w,x)\subseteq (w,x,y)\subseteq(w,x,y,z)\subseteq(w,x,y,z,3)$

Answer (score 4):

If $R$ is any integral domain which is not a field, then $(0)$ is a prime ideal in $R$, but is not a maximal ideal. For example, $R=\mathbb{Z}$ is an integral domain which is not a field.